# Error 24 too many files open

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, memory, memory-management

I am doing a game. it requires lots of images.  When using the app in normal case it will be quite running fine. But when it rash then i get the error 24 - too many files open.

I searched it but , i didn't get the appropriate answer.

please reply.

Code from comment formatted:

```
-(void)flowerImagesAnimate {
    self.flowerImage.animationImages = self.flowerArray;
    self.flowerArray = nil;
    self.flowerImage.animationDuration = 1.0;
    self.flowerImage.animationRepeatCount = 3;
    [self.flowerImage startAnimating];
}
```

– Munnu 1 hour ago

Comment: With what tools are you building your game? (Cocos2D, standard UIKit + UIImageViews, native OpenGL ES, other... ?)

Typically game engines load images into memory, requiring to open the image file only while loading its contents.

Comment: Without seeing any code, it's almost impossible to help you.

Comment: -(void)flowerImagesAnimate {
    
    self.flowerImage.animationImages = self.flowerArray;
    
    self.flowerArray = nil;
    
    self.flowerImage.animationDuration = 1.0;
    
    self.flowerImage.animationRepeatCount = 3;
    
    [self.flowerImage startAnimating];
    
}

Comment: Can you post the code where you are opening/loading the pictures/images in your app?

Comment: i am using standard UIKit + UiimageViews for loading images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't open so many files.

If you have more open than you need, close them.  If you need that many open, collect them in to 1 larger image and use portions.

Comment: i just uses the images for animation. After the animation i just releases the images also. I really dont understand what you are really talking about. How should i close my files. Can you give some code to help me. Due to this error my app crashes often.I am just using images  and videos for animation.

Comment: Of course I can't. From your question it's completely unclear what you're doing.  Nobody can help you until you actually post your code.